# Simple php/html question -- href not visible except when mouse is over

Tags: php

I have this bit of code in a .php file:

```
<?php ec3_get_events(
    5,                                          // limit
    '%DATE%: <a href="%LINK%">%TITLE%</a> (%TIME%)',  // template_event
'',                                         // template_day
'j',                                        // date_format
'<h2>%MONTH%</h2>' ); ?>
```

The link ... is only visible when the cursor is hovering over it.  I suspect it is a style setting somewhere, but I can't figure out which one it is...
TIA for tips...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [firebug instector](http://getfirebug.com/) and you will find which style it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find styles for `a` and `a:hover` in a css file (if any?).

Comment: The problem is: which .css file?  There are 5 in the theme directory, and one or two more in the plugin directory...

Answer (score 0):

How about selecting the text with firefox and then viewing the selected source code. That should do the trick.

Also if it's just a:

```
 <a href="link"> </a>
```

Try to select the container and modify it with CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.your-wrapper a { color:blue; }
</style>

<div class="your-wrapper">
    <a href="link.php">Invisible Link</a>
</div>
```

Hope it helps